# undefined error on calling classList.add in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i try to use a function already used in php - now i need it in angular.

`app.component.ts`:

```
  public showSlides(n: number) {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("slidepreview");
    if (n > slides.length) {this.slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {this.slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].classList.remove("showblock");
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[this.slideIndex-1].classList.add("showblock");
    dots[this.slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    if(this.slideIndex > slides.length){
        this.slideIndex = 1;
    }
  }
```

i call this function OnInit in ts file.

`app.component.html`

`<div class="mySlides"><img src="somepic.jpg" class="slideimage"></div>`

but i got error `cannot read property classList of undefined`
can someone help?

Comment: Are you sure that this `slides[this.slideIndex-1]` returns an actual element? Otherwise that will explain your error, as it returns `undefined`.

Comment: i have declared this as: `slideIndex: number = 1;` and in function `var slides`. the html shows that the classname exist

Comment: How exactly is your slides HTML defined? You seem to be targeting the container of the slides instead of the slides themselves.

Comment: What do you mean targeting the container? I got some divs in my html (created with `*ngFor`) and will add class "showblock" always to one of them

Comment: Call it in afterViewInit instead of onInit.

Comment: thanks Berk - exactly this was my problem - i called the function to early and so everything hanged up. Now it works

Answer (score 0):

The DOM is not rendered on OnInit point in rendering lifecycle. You can see this on this nice table: [lifecycle-hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence)

Just to solve this problem, move your code to the hook method when View is initialised.

But it's a bad practise to access to the DOM like that in Angular. You can easily manage your classes by [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)
You can get more powerfull tools to interfere in your DOM. Just use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to have access to the specific elements. Or create a [Directive](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive)